# headless chromium-browser command syntax issue

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, chrome, headless

I'm having some issue with the headless chromium-browser not creating the html files correctly.  The only thing / file that gets created is a single **{}.html** file

My domains.txt contains:

```
https://ibm.com/ 
https://www.linux.org/whats-new/
```

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 64bit linux

The command I use is below:

```
cat domains.txt | xargs -I {} -P 4 sh -c timeout 25s chromium-browser --headless --no-sandbox --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537. 36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' --dump-dom https://{} 2> /dev/null > {}.html
```

This was take from [this link](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/a-chromium-based-command-line-alternative-to-curl/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
cat domains.txt | xargs -I {} -P 4 sh -c timeout 25s chromium-browser --headless --no-sandbox --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537. 36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36' --dump-dom https://{} 2> /dev/null > {}.html
```

This lacks quotes around the argument to `sh -c`. With correct quoting, it also injects code into the the `sh -c` script from `xargs`, which is a security vulnerability.

The pipeline is better written

```
xargs -I {} -P 4 sh -c '
    timeout 25s chromium-browser \
        --headless --no-sandbox \
        --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537. 36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36" \
        --dump-dom \
        "https://$1" 2>/dev/null >"$1.html"' sh {} <domains.txt
```

... but note that this still writes to files called things like `https://ibm.com/.html` if you have those strings in the `domains.txt` file (i.e. to files in weirdly named subdirectories), and it will try to fetch URLs like `https://https://ibm.com/`.

I think the intention is to keep only the actual domains, not full URLs, in the `domains.txt` file, i.e.

```
ibm.com
www.linux.org
```

Personally, I would rather go far a simpler solution using `curl`.

Comment: Thanks...This issue is curl doesn’t parse and render JavaScript.